# getting String value from a Spinner backed by CursorAdapter from SQL query in Android

Tags: java, android, spinner, simplecursoradapter

my code here is horribly wrong, and i'm not sure how you would properly do this.  i have a Spinner which is populated from a SQLite database query through a CursorAdapter.  i need to get the text (value) of the currently selected item.  i tried this garbage:

```
((Cursor)prdSpn.getItemAtPosition(prdSpn.getSelectedItemPosition())).getString(prdSpn.getSelectedItemPosition())
```

to get the text, but it crashes every time.  what's the proper way to do this?  here's some additional code that may be relevant:

```
/// qc defined above as a SimpleCursorAdapter
/////////setup product selection spinner from db
prdSpn = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.prd_spn);
Cursor prdCur = null;
try {
    prdCur = mDb.query(smsDbSchema.ProductSchema.TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, null);
} catch(Exception e) {
    Log.e("smsdb", e.toString());
}
prdCur.moveToFirst();
startManagingCursor(prdCur);
qc = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
    this,
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
    prdCur,
    new String[] {smsDbSchema.ProductSchema.COLUMN_NAME},
    new int[] {android.R.id.text1}
);
qc.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
prdSpn.setAdapter(qc);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Code similar to the following works for me...

```
Cursor theCursor = qc.getCursor();
String theString = theCursor.getString(theCursor.getColumnIndex(<your column name here>));
```

EDIT by moonlightcheese:

implementation:

```
Cursor theCursor = (Cursor)prdSpn.getSelectedItem();
Log.e("spnERRtest", "Item: " + theCursor.getString(theCursor.getColumnIndex(smsDbSchema.ProductSchema.COLUMN_NAME)));
//theCursor.getString(theCursor.getColumnIndex(smsDbSchema.ProductSchema.COLUMN_NAME)).contains("CAR")
```

Comment: i ended up implementing something like this.  i've edited this comment beneath your earlier post to show the exact implementation.  thanks for the response.

Comment: @moonlightcheese: Glad to have been some help.

Answer (score 0):

> ((Cursor)prdSpn.getItemAtPosition(prdSpn.getSelectedItemPosition())).getString(prdSpn.getSelectedItemPosition())

I'm unclear why you are passing `getSelectedItemPosition()` to `getString()`.  Shouldn't you pass the column number of the column that has the data you want? Isn't this column unrelated to the row that was selected in the spinner?

Comment: and how would i get the appropriate columnId given the currently selected item position.

Comment: If the column id is not known, but the column name is, the standard method is to use getColumnIndex() on the cursor.